# What is the best way to convolve two matrices in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, convolution

Suppose

```
    A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
    B = [[1,2,1],[2,1,1],[1,1,2]]
```

After convolving with kernel_size=2*2 and stride=1 , the output  should be

```
[[18,18],[28,37]]
```

We need to apply convolution operation between every 2*2 portion 
        of A to every 2*2 portion of B.
        How to perform this operation efficiently using tensorflow?
        Does tensorflow has any method to do this directly?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one direct way to do it using [tf.nn.conv2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) :

```
In [1055]: A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
      ...: B = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
      ...: 

# define input tensor
In [1056]: tfA = tf.constant(A, dtype=tf.float32)

# reshape it to 4D tensor (as needed by tf.nn.conv2d)
In [1057]: tfA = tfA[tf.newaxis, :, :, tf.newaxis]

# define kernel tensor
In [1058]: tfK = tf.constant(B, dtype=tf.float32)

# again reshape it to 4D tensor (also, we use 2x2 convolution)
In [1059]: tfK = tfK[:-1, :-1, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis]

# convolving the input tensor with kernel
In [1060]: convolved = tf.nn.conv2d(tfA, tfK, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID")

In [1061]: convolved.eval()
Out[1061]: 
array([[[[ 12.],
         [ 16.]],

        [[ 24.],
         [ 28.]]]], dtype=float32)
```

I used an *interactive session* to evaluate these tensors but this should work perfectly fine even if you define the computation graph and then run it later using an explicit session.

**EDIT**

Also, to clarify, this approach will work for any `(2x2)` kernel tensor `B`. Consider the following example where the entries in the kernel tensor is doubled. As expected, the final result will also be doubled when compared to the result obtained in the above example.

Another Example :

```
In [110]: A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
In [111]: B = np.array([[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]])

In [112]: tfA = tf.constant(A, dtype=tf.float32)
In [113]: tfA = tfA[tf.newaxis, :, :, tf.newaxis]

In [114]: tfK = tf.constant(B, dtype=tf.float32)
In [115]: tfK = tfK[:-1, :-1, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis]

In [116]: convolved = tf.nn.conv2d(tfA, tfK, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID")

In [117]: convolved.eval()
Out[117]: 
array([[[[ 24.],
         [ 32.]],

        [[ 48.],
         [ 56.]]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: B can be anything ,need not be all ones.Does this work for any B?

Comment: Yes, it is generic enough to work on any Kernel tensor "B".

Comment: @phkr Added another example for clarification. Also, I'd encourage you to check it with different kernels and input tensor :)

Comment: Its not working when B=[[1,2,1],[2,1,2],[1,1,3]],when elements of B are different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will be helpful for you.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

def conv2(x, y, mode='same'):
    return np.rot90(convolve2d(np.rot90(x, 2), np.rot90(y, 2), mode=mode), 2)


A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
B = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]

print(conv2(A,B))
```

Output will be

```
[[12 21 16]
 [27 45 33]
 [24 39 28]]
```

Comment: I think OP expects to do it in tensorflow. Also, your output seems little off.

Comment: yes , I didn't applied kernel of 2X2 so output was not as expected.